# Room: Embedded и List

Tags: java, android, kotlin, room

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться, как работать в Руме с `List<MyClass>`
У меня есть большой JSON разбитый на 30+ вложенных классов.
Забираю данные из инета. Все работает отлично.

Пытаюсь записать эти данные в Room.
Чтобы вложенные классы записывались в базу данных я использую на них аннотацию `@Embedded`

Но в некоторых классах, у меня параметром приходят не просто экземпляры классов, а массивы

```
@SerializedName("availableSegments") 
var availableSegments: List<AvailableSegment>
```

если я попытаюсь повесить `@Embedded` на такой параметр, выдает ошибку

```
Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
```

Сам класс `AvailableSegment` состоит из других "кастомных" параметров (не примитивные String, Int, etc).

UPD!!!
условно...
у меня есть 3 класса:

```
@Entity(tableName = "car_table")
data class Car(
        @Embedded var zerka: Zerkala,
        @Embedded var side: Sidenia,
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var primKey: Int = 0
)


data class Zerkala(
        var kolvo: Int
)


data class Sidenia(
        var color: String
)
```

вот так - все работает.
но если в главном классе я поменяю любой параметр на массив :

```
@Entity(tableName = "car_table")
data class Car(
        @Embedded var zerka: Zerkala,
        @Embedded var side: List<Sidenia>,
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var primKey: Int = 0
)
```

Ничего не работает...

```
Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - java.util.ListD:\Program\AndroidProject\TesListRoom\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\by\wlad\koshelev\teslistroom\CarDataBaase.java:7: warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам достаточно сохранить данные без необходимости построения запросов по ним, то просто сериализуйте их. Добавьте конвертеры:

```
public class Converters {
    private static Gson gson = new Gson();
    @TypeConverter
    public static String toJson(List<AvailableSegment> segments) {
        return gson.toJson(segments);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static List<AvailableSegment> formJson(String json) {
        return gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<AvailableSegment>>(){}.getType());
    }
}
```

И добавьте их в описание room базы через `@TypeConverters(Converters.class)`. embedded при этом не нужен.

Если вам хочется через один ко многим, то через `@Relation`. Но сохранять json тогда придется разными insert'ами в каждую из таблиц отдельно, в транзакции.

```
room.runInTransaction(()->{
   carsDao.insert(cars);
   carsDao.insert(allsegments);
});
```

И соответственно relation объявлять не в entity, а в отдельном классе, который будет возвращаться в query:

```
class CarWithSegment {
    @Embedded
    public Car car;
    @Relation(parentColumn = "primKey", entityColumn = "car_id", entity = AvailableSegment.class)
    public List<AvailableSegment> availableSegments;
}
```

и в @Dao

```
@Query("select * from cars")
CarWithSegment getCarsWithSegments();
```

ЗЫ Писал в окне редактирования, могут быть синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: идеально! большое вам спасибо!